# What does the CiviCRM Contact Reference Field Drupal module do?

Tags: contacts, contact-view, contact-reference, modules

What does the CiviCRM Contact Reference Field Drupal module do? And, if I select On to enable it, the selector changes to orange, rather than green, which I assume means 'proceed with caution if enabling this module'. So I'm not enabling it. Should I?

Comment: Hi Joe, regarding the colors: what theme are you using for your admin theme?  Adminimal?

Comment: Allen, we're using Seven 7.39

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This module functions as a type of Entity Reference field so that you can link Drupal entities back to Contacts in Civi.

In the display settings for your content type, you can specify whether the Civi Contact appears as:

- a plain text name,
- their name linking to the Contact's record or
- a raw Contact ID (CID).

An example of how we use them:

We have a Drupal content type called Event.  We want staff to know who is leading the event so we include a CiviCRM Contact Reference field.  When the Event node is filled out, we choose the event leader from a Civi-linked autocomplete field.  When the node is saved and displayed, the Civi Contact Reference field displays the event leader's or leaders' name(s) so the staff person can just click on the name to go straight to the individual's contact information.

Comment: Good answer. Another use case we had was where we want to show eg Organisational Details related to the author of a drupal node, in which case we can reference the civi contact and then use Views to drop in a block show their Organisation contact details